# MySQL - Ordering by number of times value found within 'IN' statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
     SELECT Transaction.ID 
     FROM 
        Transactions 
    WHERE 
        Transaction.MetaID 
    IN (3,4,5,6) 
    ORDERBY Count(Transaction.MetaID);
```

Which obviously isn't working. Basically I would like to order the query by the number of times MetaID matches the IN statement - so some may match one of those values, others may match more others none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID 
FROM   Transactions a
WHERE  a.MetaID IN (3,4,5,6) 
GROUP  BY a.ID 
ORDER  BY COUNT(a.MetaID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by MetaID

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM   Transactions a
WHERE  a.MetaID IN (3,4,5,6) 
ORDER BY  a.MetaID;
```